# Remove in MongoDb chsarp fails when using the _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

in a sample program removing items from the mongo db doesn't work when I want to use the id.
I assume the problem is that my class has a Id Property, but mongo uses an _id ?

So when I trigger the remove in the following code nothing changes. Using remove with a query which uses name or value everything works as expected and the item gets removed.

Any hint ?

```
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(@"mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
server.Connect();
var db = server.GetDatabase("data");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Foo>("foo");

string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
Foo a = new Foo();
a.Id = id;
a.name = "Boas";
a.Value = 1;

collection.Insert<Foo>(a);
Console.WriteLine(collection.Count()+ " items"); // Count is 1
collection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id",id));
Console.WriteLine(collection.Count() + " items"); // Count is still 1 :-( should be 0
Console.ReadLine();
```

Addition:
When I use the same query with Find() the item is found. So I don't understand why find does find the element and remove doesn't remove it.

```
collection.Find(Query.EQ("_id",id)).Count() // returns 1 element
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this over and over and it continually prints out 1 items and then 0 items.  Are you sure your collection doesn't already have an item in it?

After your collection.Insert(a), add a collection.RemoveAll().

Comment: hmm i wiped the complete database and recreated a new one. now it works. a little strange. thx for your help.